# SQL Query issue: MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query returns null in MySQL. I check all things like cos, acos individually. But this query is returning NULL. Kindly help me.
altitude and latitude is the geo location of the places

```
select
acos(sin(74.338372290294) * sin(altitude) +
        cos(74.338372290294) * cos(altitude) *
        cos(latitude) - (31.552278760192)) as omg
from shk_resturants
```

Comment: I would have expected a longtitude in there more than the altitude. Most logical answer would be that eiterh altitude is null or latitude is null. Select those values as seperate columns so we can see what actual values you are putting in to that formula and we could try to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of the values in your table (latitude or altitude) are NULL, the result may be NULL also. Try to use the function

```
COALESCE(value, ...)
```

e.g.

```
select 
  acos(sin(74.338372290294) * sin(COALESCE(altitude, 0)) +
  cos(74.338372290294) * cos(COALESCE(altitude, 0)) *
  cos(COALESCE(latitude, 0)) - (31.552278760192)) as omg 
from shk_resturants
```

This returns 0 for the columns, that have NULL-values.

See: [MySQL Comparsion-Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) and: [MySQL Math-Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_acos)

Comment: I execute this query. Still having null value.

Comment: @Chintoo: What type are the columns "altitude" and "longitude" of? Please also notice, that acos() of values < -1 and > +1 is returning nullvalues also.

Answer (score 0):

acos(x) is only valid if

```
-1 <= x <= 1
```

As can be seen here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_function

So I'm guessing you put the parentheses wrong. You might have wanted to do something like

```
cos(latitude - (31.552278760192)) -- or
cos(latitude) - cos(31.552278760192)
```

at the end...? My trigonometry is too rusty to tell...